# Match JSONB row where at least one of object's values is not null

Tags: postgresql

In our database we have a data set sorta like the following:

```
+----+-------------------------------+
| id | stuff                         |
+----+-------------------------------+
| 1  | {}                            |
+----+-------------------------------+
| 2  | {"a": "something", "b": null} |
+----+-------------------------------+
| 3  | {"c": null, "d": null}        |
+----+-------------------------------+
```

I would like to match only, in this case, the one with `id = 2`, reason being that at least one of the values in the object is not null.

How can this be done with PostgreSQL?

- I know one can do something like `WHERE stuff != '{}'` but that of course only checks for an empty object
- Or something like `WHERE (stuff->>'a') IS NOT NULL`, but the thing is the list of keys in the objects are not hardcoded, could be anything

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the function [`jsonb_each_text()` or `json_each_text()`,](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html) example:

```
with my_table(id, jdata) as (
values
    (1, '{}'::jsonb),
    (2, '{"a": "something", "b": null}'),
    (3, '{"c": null, "d": null}')
)

select distinct t.*
from my_table t
cross join jsonb_each_text(jdata)
where value is not null;

 id |             jdata             
----+-------------------------------
  2 | {"a": "something", "b": null}
(1 row)
```

---

This query (proposed by Abelisto, see the comments) should be more performant on a larger dataset:

```
select t.*
from my_table t
where exists (
    select 1
    from jsonb_each_text(jdata)
    where value is not null);
```

Comment: `'{"a": "something", "b": null, "c": "another one"}'`

Comment: Actually I kept in mind something like `where exists (select 1 from jsonb_each_text(jdata) whene value is not null)` :o) IMO using `distinct` is not the most optimal (and most elegant) solution.

Comment: But the shortest one ;) No doubt your query is faster.

Comment: I'm curious to know if a `lateral join` instead of a `cross join` would result a different execution plan

Comment: @HaleemurAli - **this is** a lateral join, just a different form of notation.